# Looping in Ajax over Json data?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatable

Here is my code , I'm getting data using Ajax . yet my table isn't constructed well. so what's wrong with my code ?

```
success: function(data) {

    $('#district-table').DataTable();
      $.each(data, function() {
        $.each(data.data, function(data) {

          raw ='<tr><td>' + data['district'] + '</td><td>' + data['total'] + '</td></tr>';

          $('#district-table-body').append(raw);
        });
      });

}
```

There are no errors in Ajax nor Js , yet my 'raw' won't be displayed in my table

Controller
public function constractlocation(){

```
 $counts = DB::table('tablename')->select('district', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->groupBy('district')->get();

 $data = json_encode($counts);
 return $data;
```

}

Comment: Call `DataTable()` *after* you put the data in there. Also if you have a specific issue we need to know what the problem is, and any error messages you get. At the moment your question is unclear.

Comment: didn't work @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: change `<td>` to `</td>` before `</tr>` tag

Comment: still not working !  @n-dru

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **DataTable** plugin you don't have to traverse the JSON response by yourself

You can directly assign data to table like below..

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#district-table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "data": data
    });
}
```

Also you can embed the ajax call inside Datatable like below..

```
$('#district-table').DataTable({
    "ajax": '../path_to_controller_action',
    "columns": [
       { "data": "district" },
       { "data": "total" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Using the second method , i got this error : DataTables warning: table id=district-table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: It means your control is coming in ajax error handler. Please check if Server side implementation is working properly and its returning valid JSON.

Comment: i edited my question , check my controller please it is actually returning a valid JSOn !

Comment: i found it ! it was a get request and i was using POST ! , my request is perfectly getting the data , yet my table is empty with no errors !